# Javascript - Creating a form then adding a list inside the created form

Tags: javascript, html, css

Pretty simple, just attempting to create a new form on my HTML document then after creating the form immediately adding a list to the new form.

This is kind of what I have, there a bit of extra code but it should give a gist of what I'm attempting to achieve:

The code works for me with the exception of the line "var newmodelli = document.getElementById('modelstatline' + (count + 1));" because you can't get an ID by adding the count it seems. So I need an alternate way to achieve what I need instead of adding it like so.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
div {
 position: relative;
 left: 50px;
    width: 600px;
 height: 300px;
    border: 20px solid rgb(0, 255, 0);
 background-color: black;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
}
#a {
    float: left;
 display: block;
    padding: 7px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 15px;
 background-color: black;
 color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}
#b {
 float: left;
 display: block;
    padding: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 16px;
}
li {
 display: block;
}
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
option {
 color: black;
 font-size: 15px;
}
select {
 color: black;
 font-size: 15px;
 width: 95px;
 height: 23px;
 text-align: center;
}
input {
 width:25px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: black;
}
button {
 width: 22px;
 text-align: center;
}

</style>
<script>
var count = 1;
var newF = document.createElement('form');
 newF.id = 'modelstatline' + (count + 1);
var newli = document.createElement('li');
 newli.id = 'a';
var newInM = document.createElement('input');
 newInM.type = 'text';
 newInM.name = 'WS' + (count + 1);

function addModelstatline()
{
 var newmodelform = document.getElementById('modelstatlinegrp');
// [this is where the error lies] var newmodelli = document.getElementById('modelstatline' + (count + 1));
 if (count < 4)
 {
  newmodelform.appendChild(newF);
  // [child of error] newmodelli.appendChild(newli);
  // aModelstatline.appendChild(newInM);
  count++;
 }
 else
 {
  alert('Too many');
 }
}
</script>

<div>
<ul id="modelstatlinegrp">
<form id="modelstatline1">
 <li id="a">Model Statline 1<br />
 <button type="button" onclick="javascript: addModelstatline();">+</button>
 <li id="a">M<br /><input type="text" name="M1"></li>
 <li id="a">WS<br /><input style="width:14px" type="text" name="WS1"><b style="font-size:20px"> +</b></li>
 <li id="a">BS<br /><input style="width:14px" type="text" name="BS1"><b style="font-size:20px"> +</b></li>
 <li id="a">S<br /><input type="text" name="S1"></li>
 <li id="a">T<br /><input type="text" name="T1"></li>
 <li id="a">W<br /><input type="text" name="W1"></li>
 <li id="a">A<br /><input type="text" name="A1"></li>
 <li id="a">Ld<br /><input type="text" name="Ld1"></li>
 <li id="a">Sv<br /><input style="width:14px" type="text" name="Sv1"><b style="font-size:20px">+</b></li>
</form>
</ul>
<br />
<br />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing and what have you done to try and fix the problem? Have you checked your browser console for errors and would it be possible for you to include the relevant html. Not sure why you don't have the `document.createElement()`'s within your if condition though...

Comment: Yes sorry, to create a new form after one already exists. I'll edit and add the HTML, what I have at least.

Comment: The code works for me with the exception of the line "var newmodelli = document.getElementById('modelstatline' + (count + 1));" because you can't get an ID by adding the count it seems. So I need an alternate way to achieve what I need instead of adding it like so.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, not totally sure what you want but it something like this, I think.

```js
let form = document.createElement('form');
form.id = 'modelstatline2';

document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(form);

for (let ix = 1; ix < 4; ix++) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.id = 'a';

  let input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'text';
  input.name = 'WS' + ix;

  li.appendChild(input);
  form.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Great answer but I think the idea behind `function addModelstatline()` is to allow the client to click a button or something to then add one more form to the page but setting a limit of **3**. I could be wrong but it would be the only reason I can think of having it in a function and "add" in the function name. I can only make the assumption since the OP has failed to include the relevant HTML.

Comment: Sorry for not including the HTML, just added it now.

Comment: Essentially, hitting the button adds the form with "newmodelform.appendChild(newF);" and works fine, Just adding a list inside of this created form is the hard part because I can't find the ID dynamically.